# jQuery UI Datepicker set regional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Datepicker from the jQuery UI library. The website in which I use it has localization support. So I need to use localization for the datepicker too, also known as regional.

This is how I set the regional of the datepicker:

`$(element).datepicker($.datepicker.regional[window.culture.language])`

Language can be 'en', 'fr', 'es and so on, just letters iso format.

I tried manually getting the regional format by typing in the browser console:

```
$.datepicker.regional[window.culture.language]
```

And it returns a regional object with the right translations.

The thing is I have jquery ui version 1.12.1 and the jquery ui i18n file with the datepicker translations version 1.11.4.

Comment: Are you actually loading the "fr" and "es" translation files in your code ? You need to load the library's javascript file and if it's in another language than English, you need to load another file for the translations.

Comment: if I didn't load them, the the `$.datepicker.regional[window.culture.language]` command should not return a valid javascript object with the translations, I tried it with french and it works

Comment: what do you see when running `console.log(window.culture.language);` ?